# JavaScript - Return individual values from one array, inside of a for-of loop calling another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-of-loop

I'm returning two values, `svcCenterBands` `sortedBands`, from one function and calling `sortedBands` inside a `for of` loop inside of another function.

`svcCenterBands` is an array of objects inside of the `getMileageBand` function that returns an array of unique objects that are string values representing a range of miles.

```
const getMileageBand = refSrcData => {
    const mileageBand = refSrcData.data.map(e => e['97']); // Mileage Band Name

    // Reduce the array to only unique values, no repeats
    const svcCenterBands = mileageBand.reduce((unique, i) => {
        if (!unique.some(obj => obj.label === i.label && obj.value === i.value)) {
            unique.push(i);
        }
        return unique;
    }, []);

    // Get only the values from svcCenterBands
    const numberedBands = svcCenterBands
        .map(band => Object.values(band))
        .join()
        .split('-')
        .map(str => str.split(',')[0]);

    // Sort numberedBands in ascending order
    const sortedBands = numberedBands
        .map(Number)
        .sort((first, next) => first - next);

    console.log(svcCenterBands, sortedBands);
    return [svcCenterBands, sortedBands];
};
```

`sortedBands` goes a bit further and takes `svcCenterBands`, grabs only it's last value and converts that to a number and sorts it. For example, if `svcCenterBands` returns a value of `["0-30"]`, `sortedBands` takes that string inside of the array and extracts the number past the hyphen, converts it to a number and sorts all array values in ascending order.

Inside of another function, I'm calling `getMileageBand` and running `sortedBands` (`getMileageBand(facData)[1]`) through a `for of` loop.

```
    const mileageRanges = getMileageBand(facData)[0];
    const mileageBand = getMileageBand(facData)[1];

    // generate radius for each mileage band, mileage === coordinates
    for (mileage of mileageBand) {
        // for (mileage of getMileageBand(facData)) {
        ...
        // console.log(mileageRanges.map(range => range.value));

        const mileageValue = `${mileageRanges.map(range => range.value)} miles`;
        ...
```

I can get the values for `sortedBands` no problem which is what I need to generate my radial bands on my map.

[image]

But I'm trying to iterate through the values of `svcCenterBands` inside of the  `for (mileage of mileageBand)` loop, but I'm getting the array of objects when I log `mileageRanges` inside of the `mileageBand` band for loop.

[image]

If i log `mileageRange[mileage]` with the `for of` index, I only get the first value in `mileageRange` and undefined for the rest.

[image]

What I would like to see is the values inside of the array of objects by their range, which I can get when I call `getMileageBand` but I can't get these values inside of the `for of` loop.

This is what I'm trying to get inside of the `for of` loop:

[image]

This is what shows up on my screen beneath my map with radial bands.

[image]

Ultimately, I'd like each card to show a sequence of 0-30, 31-60, etc. instead of all values being displayed in each card.

I can't include all of my code to test because it's too much and too many environment variables to extract the data I'm pulling from the database, so I included as much code as I could to back up my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to grab the element from mileageRanges which is at the same index as the current element of mileageBand in your for..of loop.  I would suggest not using for..of in this case as I dont believe it provides the index.  Here is a simple for loop.

```js
const [mileageRanges, mileageBand] = getMileageBand(facData); // just call that expensive function once.

for (let i=0; i < mileageBand.length; i++) {
  const mileage = mileageBand[i];
  const mileageRange = mileageRanges[i].value;
}
```